# React-hook-form: why is `useForm` not taking type arguments?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm implementing a basic user signup form with react-hook-form in Typescript. The following code works fine:

```
import React, { SyntheticEvent } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "@reach/router";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
}

type Inputs = {
  user: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  }
}

const SignupPage: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const createUser = (data: Inputs) => console.log(data);

  const { errors, handleSubmit, register } = useForm();

  return(
    <form action="#" onSubmit={handleSubmit(createUser)}>
      <label htmlFor="user[email]">Email address</label>
      <input
        name="user[email]"
        placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
        type="text"
        ref={register({ required: true, pattern: /@/ })}
      />
      {errors.user?.email?.type === "required" && "Email can't be blank"}
      {errors.user?.email?.type === "pattern" && 'Email must include an "@"'}

      <label htmlFor="user[password]">Password</label>
      <input
        name="user[password]"
        placeholder="Minimum 6 characters"
        type="password"
        ref={register({ minLength: 6 })}
      />
      {errors.user?.password && 'Password must be at least 6 characters'}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;
```

Where I run into trouble is trying to use type arguments with `useForm`. When I change the pertinent line to:

```
  const { errors, handleSubmit, register } = useForm<Inputs, any>();
```

...compilation fails with `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 2.`

Now, the API documentation for react-hook-form suggests that this would work, which, whatever, documentation can be and often is wrong. But I'm also looking at the source, for react-hook-form v5.6.1, which is what I've confirmed I'm using, and this is how `useForm` is defined [in the source](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/v5.6.1/src/useForm.ts#L68):

```
export function useForm<
  FormValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  ValidationContext extends object = object
>({ 
   // various parameters here 
})
```

So I'm thinking that the docs are right after all, and I'm doing something wrong. Little help?

Comment: It is working on my local environment with react-hook-form v5.4.2 - Not sure if it can help.
Also react-hook-form contributors have a support spectrum channel, they answer pretty quickly

Comment: For the record, I did try downgrading to v5.4.2, same problem there. Thanks for the tip about the support channel, I will try there.